# Flagging late comments on old, closed questions

Tags: discussion

A couple years ago (2014) a question was asked.  I answered, but the question was eventually closed as too broad.

9 hours ago I received two comments on my answer.  The comments provide additional examples requesting explanation.  Are those comments worth flagging as possibly being intended as a question?  I don't think it makes sense to amend an old answer to a closed question.

Comment: I get that from time to time, I answer in a comment if I can be bothered and ignore them elsewise. I don't think it's worth bothering moderators with a flag, if they don't get an answer they can go ahead and make it a question. In my opinion.

Comment: You have no obligation whatsoever to respond to a user that does not want to click the Ask Question button.  Consider flagging it as "not constructive".

Comment: If you think the examples are a useful expansion on the question asked you can suggest to the commentors to ask a new specific question about their examples, referencing the old question and your answer.